# find neighbours in 2d array by position of elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I need to find neighbours in 2d array by position of elements

**Data available :**

**Size of the grid**. e.g - 3*3 will return 3, 4*4 will return 4

**number of filled cells in the grid** . e.g - 4

**get x co-ordinate of filled cell** - e.g 0 or 1 or 2 etc

**get y co-ordinate of filled cell** - e.g 0 or 1 or 2 etc

e.g

```
int[][] room = {
            {0, 0, X},
            {0, X, 0},
            {X, 0, 0}
    };
```

Here, Size of the grid = 3

number of filled cells in the grid = 3 (as there are three 'X', it does not matter what value it has on other cells)

get x co-ordinate of filled cell - for 1st element it is 0, for 2nd element it is 1, for 3rd element it is 2

get y co-ordinate of filled cell - for 1st element it is 2, for 2nd element it is 1, for 3rd element it is 0

so, co-ordinates become (0,2),(1,1),(2,0)

I need to find the count the number of 'X' with at least one neighbouring 'X'. 'X' are considered neighbours if they are next to each other in the cardinal directions, but not the diagonals.
So above case would return 0.

```
int[][] room = {
            {X, X, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0}
    };
```

this should return 2.

Language i am using is Java.

i tried iterating over the number of filled elements and use neighbour logic like below but it breaks for some or the other cases
Neighbor above you = (x, y-1),

Neighbor below you = (x, y+1),

Neighbor on your left = (x-1, y),

Neighbor on your right = (x+1, y)

```
for (int x = 0; x < nums; x++) {
        int xcord = xmap.get(x); //return x cord
        int ycord = ymap.get(x); //return y cord
        int xcordLeft = x - 1 >= 0 ? xmap.get(x - 1) : 0;
        int ycordLeft = x - 1 >= 0 ? ymap.get(x - 1) : 0;

        int xcordRight = x + 1 < size ? xmap.getOrDefault(x + 1, 0) : 0;
        int ycordRight = x + 1 < size ? ymap.getOrDefault(x + 1, 0) : 0;

        int xcordTop = xcord - 1 >= 0 ? xmap.get(xcord - 1) : 0;
        int ycordTop = ymap.get(ycord);

        int ycordBottom = ymap.get(ycord);*/
        //left
        if (xcord >= 0 && x - 1 >= 0 && xcord == xcordLeft && ycord - 1 == ycordLeft) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        //right
        if (xcord >= 0 && x + 1 < size && xcord == xcordRight && ycord + 1 == ycordRight) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        //top
        if (xcord >= 0 && xcord - 1 >= 0 && xcord - 1 == xcordTop && ycord == ycordTop) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        //bottom
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working from a list of coordinates that specify where the X's are.

Two cells *p*(*x*<sub>*p*</sub>, *y*<sub>*p*</sub>) are *q*(*x*<sub>*q*</sub>, *y*<sub>*q*</sub>) adjacent when their Manhattan distance is one:

| *x*<sub>*p*</sub> − *x*<sub>*q*</sub> |
            + | *y*<sub>*p*</sub> − *y*<sub>*q*</sub> | = 1

Instead of trying to find the coordinates of the top, bottom, left and right neighbours and look them up in your list, iterate over the list and count the neighbours:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    int x = xmap.get(i);
    int y = ymap.get(i);
    int neighbors = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < nums; j++) {
        int xx = xmap.get(j);
        int yy = ymap.get(j);

        if ((abs(x - xx) + abs(y - yy) == 1) {
            neighbors++;
        }
    }

    if (neighbors) // do stuff
}
```

The Manhattan distance of a cell to itself is 0, so it doesn't count as neighbour. That code is not very efficient for large, dense grids, but if you have few X's, the nested lops should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Make it plain and simple.
Count the neighbours by checking all four adjacent coordinates, and have some condition that checks whether an adjacent coordinate is in bounds:

```
bool inBounds(int x, int y){
    return 0 <= x and x < size and 0 <= y and y < size;
}

int countNeighbours(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=-1; i<=1; i+=2){
        if(inBounds(x+i, y))
            if(data[x+i][y] == X){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(inBounds(x, y+i))
            if(data[x][y+i] == X){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int countGroupedEntries(){
    int count = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<size; y++){
            if(data[x][y] == X){
                if(countNeighbours(x,y) != 0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I mean, some algorithm might be smarter about things here, but if you don't have some efficiency chokepoint, make the algorithm as simple as possible, make it readable (not that this algorithm is particularly bad, works in Θ(size²) just fine, only thing to consider is the linear factor).
Doing the `inBounds` check rather than making sure you stay in bounds by special cases keeps the `countNeighbours` method from overcrowding.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to count the amount of neigbourhood relations you can:

```
private int countNeighborRelations(int[][] array, int yourX) {
    int neighborRelationCount = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length - 1; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] == yourX && array[y][x + 1] == yourX) {
                neighborRelationCount += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] == yourX && array[y + 1][x] == yourX) {
                neighborRelationCount += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return neighborRelationCount;
}
```

If you like to count how many of your X have neigbourHoodRelations (in other words all X how have at least one neighbor) you can use following code:

```
private int countNeighbors(int[][] array, int yourX) {
    int[][] neighborRelationCount = new int[array.length][array[0].length];
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length - 1; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] == yourX && array[y][x + 1] == yourX) {
                neighborRelationCount[y][x]++;
                neighborRelationCount[y][x + 1]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] == yourX && array[y + 1][x] == yourX) {
                neighborRelationCount[y][x]++;
                neighborRelationCount[y + 1][x]++;
            }
        }
    }
    int neighbourCount=0;
    for (int y = 0; y < neighborRelationCount.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < neighborRelationCount[y].length; x++) {
            if (0<neighborRelationCount[y][x]) {
                neighbourCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbourCount;
}
```

Of course there are simpler solutions if you do use other data format, but with primitive int[][] i'think it's the most simple way.

Here is how I tested the functionality:

```
    @Test
    public void testRelations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[][] room0_0 = { { 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1 } };
        int[][] room2_2 = { { 1, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
        int[][] room4_3 = { { 1, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
        int[][] room4_4 = { { 1, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 1 } };
        int[][] room8_5 = { { 1, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 1 } };
        int[][] room24_9 = { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 } };
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room0_0, 1)==0);
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room2_2, 1)==2);
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room4_3, 1)==4);
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room4_4, 1)==4);
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room8_5, 1)==8);
        assertTrue(countNeighborRelations(room24_9, 1)==24);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room0_0, 1)==0);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room2_2, 1)==2);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room4_3, 1)==3);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room4_4, 1)==4);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room8_5, 1)==5);
        assertTrue(countNeighbors(room24_9, 1)==9);
    }
```

**EDIT added full implementations for full requested functionality**

*Following Code has Complexity of O(gridSize^2)*

```
private int neigbours(Collection<CoordinatedObject> cos,int gridSize) {
    boolean[][] array=new boolean[gridSize][gridSize];
    for(CoordinatedObject co:cos) {
        array[co.getX()][co.getY()]&=true;
    }
    boolean[][] neighborRelations = new boolean[array.length][array[0].length];
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length - 1; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] && array[y][x + 1]) {
                neighborRelations[y][x]&=true;
                neighborRelations[y][x + 1]&=true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] && array[y + 1][x]) {
                neighborRelations[y][x]&=true;
                neighborRelations[y + 1][x]&=true;
            }
        }
    }
    int neighbourCount=0;
    for (int y = 0; y < neighborRelations.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < neighborRelations[y].length; x++) {
            if (neighborRelations[y][x]) {
                neighbourCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbourCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @samuel. But i think it does not work. I called countNeighbors method from my loop passing first array and x-cord it returns 6,0,0 (three iterations) when ideally should have returned 0.

Comment: may i ask how you test it? i've also added my test for comparison ;)

Comment: I see. you are passing element value as 'yourX'. unfortunately array is not available in original question but just the co-ordinates. but i guess i can populate the array using those co-ordinates and then pass that value.

Comment: Ok, sorry, seems i missunderstood your question, but with your guess it will work sure.

Comment: @SCoder If added a full solution for your code.

If you do not need performance the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615990/12558456) in my opinion is better (more readable)

If you need very high performance over all, you may also combine both solutions. As the other has a Compexitivity of O(n^2) and mine one of O(greedSize^2) the other may is faster for large loose grids. (if n<greedSize)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing the coordinate of all x  in two maps in sequence(one for x and one for y). 
so for example

```
    {X , X , 0 , X},
    {X , 0 , X , X}
    {0 , 0 , X , X}
    {X , X,  0 , 0}
```

so your map would have entry like this

```
    xmap = {
            0 : 0,
            1 : 1,
            2 : 3,
            3 : 0,
            4 : 2,
            5 : 3,
            6 : 2,
            7 : 3,
            8 : 0,
            9 : 1
        }
    ymap = {
            0 : 0,
            1 : 0,
            2 : 0,
            3 : 1,
            4 : 1,
            5 : 1,
            6 : 2,
            7 : 2,
            8 : 3,
            9 : 3,
        }
```

I think left and right can be edited like this

```
      //left
        if (xcord >= 0 && x - 1 >= 0 && xcord - 1 == xcordLeft && ycord == ycordLeft) {
            neighbours++; //comparing (x - 1 , y) && (x , y)
        }
      //right
        if (xcord >= 0 && x + 1 < size && xcord + 1 == xcordRight && ycord == ycordRight) {
            neighbours++; // comparing(x , y) && (x + 1 , y)
        }
```

actually xcordTop should be ycordTop but let us suppose it is equivalent to finding top element

```
the mistake you are doing is that how can you be sure that
int xcordTop = xcord - 1 >= 0 ? xmap.get(xcord - 1) : 0; will give you coordinate of just upper element, because key of
the map is not x coordinates it is just numbering of X'S
```

so for 7th X(whose index is 6 in 0 based numbering) in the given matrix, lets us take it's x and y coordinate

```
xcord = 2 
ycord = 2
now let's us take xmap.get(2)
what do we get xcordTop = 0
```

even if we go from ycordTop logic , it is again will given us wrong coordinate as map key values are just value of sequence of
total X

```
so let's take ymap.get(ycord) 
ycord = 2
so ycordTop = ymap.get(2) 
we get ycordTop = 0 so which is 0th row
```

so a simple solution is to just traverse the 2d array
and check for all the neighbors like you mentioned which will be

```
for(int y = 0; y < array.length; ++y){
    for(int x = 0; x < array[y].length; ++x){
        if(array[x][y] == 'X'){
            if(x - 1 >= 0 && array[x - 1][y] == 'X'){
                ++neighbors;
            }
            else if(x + 1 < array[y].length && array[x + 1][y] == 'X'){
                ++neighbors;
            }
            else if(y - 1 >= 0  && array[x][y - 1] == 'X'){
                ++neighbors;
            }
            else if(y + 1 < array.length && array[x][y + 1] == 'X'){
                ++neighbors;
            }
        }
    }
}
```